# Run "yes 0 | script -c 'ispell text.txt' /dev/null" on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, scripting, command-line-interface, ispell

I am getting crazy, on my Linux machine I would run:

```
yes 0 | script -c 'ispell text.txt' /dev/null
```

With any problem. Unfortunately on Mac OS X the command `script` is not accepting the '-c' option:

```
script: illegal option -- c
```

I installed with brew: binutils, coreutils and other packages .. but there is no `script` or `script` alternative command anywhere.

I found on Google that the package under Linux is util-linux: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/

But there is no way to find it for mac OS X nor in a compiled package nor in brew source.

Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

PS: my final aim is to achieve this: [Spell checking a file using command line, non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453196/spell-checking-a-file-using-command-line-non-interactively)

Comment: What is `script`? bash DOES support `-c`, as does any POSIX compatible shell.

Comment: Unfortunately '-c' is not supported by the bash bundled with Mac OS X Sierra, neither by the one within brew....

Comment: Reading the man page for OSX bashsays otherwide: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html

Comment: The command is 'script', it is not an option of 'bash': https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html (this is in Darwin) - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html this is in Linux...

Comment: This is the '-c' option part that is missing in the BSD version of 'script' present in Darwin.. "-c, --command command
              Run the command rather than an interactive shell.  This makes
              it easy for a script to capture the output of a program that
              behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty."

Comment: So it have nothing to do with bash, but rater the command called `script`. Installing a newer version of bash will not make another command support more flags.

Comment: You missed completely the point: I want to install a new version of the `script` command which supports `-c` option. What has bash to do with it?

Comment: @shaice - the point is, this is not a bash question, yet you've tagged your question [tag:bash]. And it's not a programming question, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow (hence my close vote). You will likely have better luck and fewer downvotes on http://Superuser.com/ or [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If the command `script` doesn't support a `-c` flag one can then you to add the command as stdin:

```
echo 'ispell text.txt' | script /dev/null
```

But looking at that command it seems like you are using it wrong as the output file is `/dev/null`.

Instead use:

```
bash -c 'ispell text.txt'
```

Or even:

```
ispell text.txt
```

Comment: I need to pass 'yes 0' to ispell to use it non-interactively as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453196/spell-checking-a-file-using-command-line-non-interactively. _You need the script command because some commands like ispell doesn't want to be scripted. Normally you would pipe the output of yes 0 to a command to simulate hitting the "0" key all the time but some commands detect being scripted and refuse to cooperate_ And the command `script` **supports** `-c` but not in Darwin (I dunno why)